# How can I ignore '|' pipe delimiter reading Google Sheet data in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I am using Google Sheets as data stores populated by Supermetrics. I need to read these in Google BigQuery to join multiple sources and manipulate the data using SQL.

When I'm pulling my sting fields, some of which contain the pipe character '|' BQ is automatically delimiting these populating fields with the wrong data and causing queries to fail.

Is there a way to connect to Google Sheets and tell BQ to ignore the pipe characters?

with an example field of:

```
test~wm~helo_thisisafield_bn~thisisanotherfieldbm|H4|Hello
```

BQ is reading this as three fields:

```
test~wm~helo_thisisafield_bn~thisisanotherfieldbm, H4, Hello
```

which is not matching the schema set. I can't account for this in the schema as the number of and presence of the | is not fixed.

Is there any way I can ignore this? I can set a delimiter pulling data from a CSV but not from Google Sheets afaict.

So far the only solution I've managed is to read the whole spreadsheet in one field and split in SQL which is not ideal.

Comment: how many fields are there in that example? 2? 3? 1?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa In the example there is one field, it is, however, being broken down into 3 fields when BQ reads the Google Sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the table in BigQuery, after choosing Google Drive for Location and specifying the URL of a Google Sheet, instead of choosing Google Sheet in File Format, choose CSV.

You'll then have the possibility to specify the delimiter down in the creation options. Choose comma, oddly enough it works for me although the file is a Google Sheet.